# Apply rolling function to groupby over several columns

Tags: pandas, group-by, time-series

I'd like to apply rolling functions to a dataframe grouped by two columns with repeated date entries. Specifically, with both "freq" and "window" as datetime values, not simply ints.

In principle, I'm try to combine the methods from [How to apply rolling functions in a group by object in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28642511/how-to-apply-rolling-functions-in-a-group-by-object-in-pandas) and [pandas rolling sum of last five minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27062652/pandas-rolling-sum-of-last-five-minutes).

**Input**

Here is a sample of the data, with one id=33 although we expect several id's.

```
X = [{'date': '2017-02-05', 'id': 33, 'item': 'A', 'points': 20},
 {'date': '2017-02-05', 'id': 33, 'item': 'B', 'points': 10},
 {'date': '2017-02-06', 'id': 33, 'item': 'B', 'points': 10},
 {'date': '2017-02-11', 'id': 33, 'item': 'A', 'points': 1},
 {'date': '2017-02-11', 'id': 33, 'item': 'A', 'points': 1},
 {'date': '2017-02-11', 'id': 33, 'item': 'A', 'points': 1},
 {'date': '2017-02-13', 'id': 33, 'item': 'A', 'points': 4}]

# df = pd.DataFrame(X) and reindex df to pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df

            id item  points
date                       
2017-02-05  33    A      20
2017-02-05  33    B      10
2017-02-06  33    B      10
2017-02-11  33    A       1
2017-02-11  33    A       1
2017-02-11  33    A       1
2017-02-13  33    A       4
```

**Goal**

Sample each 'id' every 2 days (freq='2d') and return the sum of total points for each item over the previous three days (window='3D'), end-date inclusive

**Desired Output**

```
            id    A    B
date                       
2017-02-05  33    20   10
2017-02-07  33    20   30    
2017-02-09  33    0    10
2017-02-11  33    3    0
2017-02-13  33    7    0
```

E.g. on the right-inclusive end-date 2017-02-13, we sample the 3-day period 2017-02-11 to 2017-02-13. In this period, id=33 had a sum of A points equal to 1+1+1+4 = 7

**Attempts**

An attempt of groupby with a pd.rolling_sum as follows didn't work, due to repeated dates

```
df.groupby(['id', 'item'])['points'].apply(pd.rolling_sum, freq='4D', window=3)
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Also note that from the documentation http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.rolling_apply.html 'window' is an int representing the size sample period, not the number of days to sample.

We can also try resampling and using last, however the desired look-back of 3 days doesn't seem to be used

```
df.groupby(['id', 'item'])['points'].resample('2D', label='right', closed='right').\
apply(lambda x: x.last('3D').sum())

id  item  date      
33  A     2017-02-05    20
          2017-02-07     0
          2017-02-09     0
          2017-02-11     3
          2017-02-13     4
    B     2017-02-05    10
          2017-02-07    10
```

Of course,setting up a loop over unique id's ID, selecting df_id = df[df['id']==ID], and summing over the periods does work but is computationally-intensive and doesn't exploit groupby's nice vectorization.

Thanks to @jezrael for good suggestions so far

**Notes**

Pandas version = 0.20.1

I'm a little confused as to why the documentation on rolling() here:https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html
suggests that the "window" parameter can be in an int or offset but on attempting df.rolling(window='3D',...) I get`raise ValueError("window must be an integer")`

It appears that the above documentation is not consistent with the latest code for rolling's window from ./core/window.py :
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/window.py

```
elif not is_integer(self.window):
            raise ValueError("window must be an integer")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- It's easiest to handle `resample` and `rolling` with date frequencies when we have a single level datetime index.
- However, I can't `pivot`/`unstack` appropriately without dealing with duplicate `A`/`B`s so I `groupby` and `sum`
- I `unstack` one level `date` so I can `fill_value=0`.  Currently, I can't `fill_value=0` when I `unstack` more than one level at a time.  I make up for it with a transpose `T`
- Now that I've got a single level in the index, I reindex with a date range from the min to max values in the index
- Finally, I do a rolling 3 day sum and resample that result every 2 days with `resample`
- I clean this up with a bit of renaming indices and one more pivot.

---

```
s = df.set_index(['id', 'item'], append=True).points
s = s.groupby(level=['date', 'id', 'item']).sum()

d = s.unstack('date', fill_value=0).T
tidx = pd.date_range(d.index.min(), d.index.max())
d = d.reindex(tidx, fill_value=0)

d1 = d.rolling('3D').sum().resample('2D').first().astype(d.dtypes).stack(0)
d1 = d1.rename_axis(['date', 'id']).rename_axis(None, 1)
print(d1)

                A   B
date       id        
2017-02-05 33  20  10
2017-02-07 33  20  20
2017-02-09 33   0   0
2017-02-11 33   3   0
2017-02-13 33   7   0
```

Comment: thanks for the explanations. any tips on working with accessing datetime values in rolling methods (e.g. time of most recent nonzero entry in a given window)? at the moment, it seems only arrays of floats X can be accessed in calls like d.rolling('3D').apply(lambda X: func(X)).resample('2D')

Comment: That sounds like it should be a separate question.  The tip would be to use `pd.Series.first_valid_index` or `pd.Series.last_valid_index` after having masked the zeros as `np.nan`.  You can do some other tricks in `numpy` as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(X) 

# group sum by day
df = df.groupby(['date', 'id', 'item'])['points'].sum().reset_index().sort_values(['date', 'id', 'item'])

# convert index to datetime index
df = df.set_index('date')
df.index = DatetimeIndex(df.index)

# rolloing sum by 3D
df['pointsum'] = df.groupby(['id', 'item']).transform(lambda x: x.rolling(window='3D').sum())

# reshape dataframe
df = df.reset_index().set_index(['date', 'id', 'item'])['pointsum'].unstack().reset_index().set_index('date').fillna(0)

df
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to address the '2D' sampling frequency?

Comment: can it be add in "x.rolling(window='3D')"? The sample data is too little for me to understand whole question.

Comment: see piRsquared's answer :-)